# What should be the query for table empsalary(empid,salary,designation) when i want to find the maximum salary of the designation manager and clerk

Tags: sql

When i want to print the maximum salary of designation manager and clerk and i apply:

```
select empid,max(salary) 
from empsalary 
where designation='manager' or designation='clerk'
```

then it gives error that:

> empid is not included in aggegate function or group by

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you are missing a `group by` clause:

```
select designation, max(salary) 
from empsalary 
where designation = 'manager' or designation = 'clerk'
group by designation
```

If you need the ids of clerks and managers with the maximum salary, you must join this query to the table:

```
select empid, designation, salary
from empsalary e inner join (
    select designation, max(salary) 
    from empsalary 
    where designation = 'manager' or designation = 'clerk'
    group by designation
) g on g.designation = e.designation and g.salary = e.salary
```

Comment: I have done the grouping but it is showing all the manager's salary but i just want the details of manager with max salart

Comment: Then you need the 2nd query.

Comment: But what is the problem in 1st query

Comment: My 1st query returns the max salary of managers and the max salary of clerks.

Comment: Can you please explain the functioning of 2nd query

Comment: The 2nd query returns the details of the employees that match the results of the subquery, meaning only those employees that are managers or clerks **and** have the maximum salary of their designation. This is why I joined the table to the subquery. To match specific salaries and designations.

Comment: The subquery will return all the managers salary as it was happening in first query then how it will choose the manager and clerk having highest salary

Comment: `select designation, max(salary)...` does not return all the managers and clerks salaries. It returns the maximum salary for each of the 2 designations, so the result is 2 rows with the designation and the salary.

Comment: Thnxx for the explanation

Comment: @AkhandChaurasia if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the empid in the select part of your query.
Move the `designation` field to this part.

```sql
SELECT designation, Max(salary)
FROM   empsalary
WHERE  designation = 'manager' OR designation = 'clerk' 
GROUP BY designation ;
```

The output should be 2 rows (assuming there is at least one record with 'manager' and 'clerk' values).

Comment: It won't work without the GROUP BY statement (at least on mssql)

Comment: You are correct, looks like it was removed during my code styling. I updated the answer.